# How to change pandas MultiIndex name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to change the pandas multi-index name as follows and encountered this strange issue. Is this a bug? My pandas version is 1.5.3.

[image]

Comment: Please make sure to provide a reproducible input, images are not allowed. You should use `df_tmp.index = df_tmp.index.set_names(('e', 'f'))`

Comment: Or `df_tmp.index.names = ('e', 'f')` (note the **s**).